# Yoast's rel=“next” & rel=“prev” tag don't work on static homepage's paginated pages

Tags: pagination

Yoast support says

> "Our plugin utilizes the built-in WordPress core functions to
>   recognize pagination. Some plugins and theme developers have modified
>   or created their method of adding pagination. In these cases, custom
>   code may need to be written by a developer to pass information between
>   our plugin and the plugin or theme creating the pagination. The
>   wpseo_prev_rel_link and wpseo_next_rel_link filters can be used to
>   customize pagination output". Some examples can be [found here](https://gist.github.com/amboutwe/66c583d2ef4015a8a244ee3e0e8cd1a0).

But I don't know, how to write custom code to enable rel=“next” & rel=“prev” tag on Static Homepage's paginated pages.

Please Help!

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The static front page option is specifically for a front page without pagination. If your homepage has pagination, shouldn't it be set to display your latest posts?

Comment: The latest posts are displayed with pagination on the homepage. I used the term "Static" because I configured the homepage by heading over WordPress Settings >> Reading settings>> Static page.

I tried these custom codes to enable rel=”next” and rel=”prev” from GitHub (https://github.com/Yoast/wordpress-seo/issues/437) but did not work.